# how do you implement classes with property subsets?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have 3 classes ...

```
class1 {
  constructor(a, b, c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.toClass2 = function() {
      // TODO: return this as an instance of class2;
      // the conversion would remove the unwanted 'b' property
    }
    this.toClass3 = function() {
      // TODO: return this as an instance of class3;
      // the conversion would remove the unwanted 'a' property
    }
  }
}

class2 {
  constructor(a, c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.c = c;
  }
}

class3 {
  constructor(b, c) {
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

The following statements are true ...

- class1 could extend class2
- class1 could extend class3
- class1 could NOT extend class2 AND class3 (multiple inheritance not supported in JavaScript and multiple inheritance would give the derived class 4 properties, but I only want 3)
- class2 has a subset of class1's properties
- class3 has a subset of class1's properties

QUESTION: How can I best implement the classes in JavaScript or TypeScript so that the toClass2 and toClass3 conversion methods work? Are there any design patterns for this? Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What doesn't work with your conversion methods? How are you planing on using these classes?

Comment: i want to know how to have a class that provides methods that return instances of other classes. Those other classes will only have properties that are subsets of the main class. Its not a case of it not working - anyone could get this to work - the question is what is the best approach to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to implement what you require, but you probably just showed a minimal example, and the best approach depends on a more detailed explanation of what you're actually doing.

In general, assuming your example, here are a few ways I can think of.

(1) The obvious way ([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09private%20b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09private%20c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(a%3A%20any%2C%20b%3A%20any%2C%20c%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.a%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.b%20%3D%20b%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.c%20%3D%20c%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09toB()%3A%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20B(this.a%2C%20this.c)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09toC()%3A%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20C(this.a%2C%20this.b)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09private%20c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(a%3A%20any%2C%20c%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.a%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.c%20%3D%20c%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09private%20b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(a%3A%20any%2C%20b%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.a%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.b%20%3D%20b%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
class A {
    private a: any;
    private b: any;
    private c: any;

    constructor(a: any, b: any, c: any) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    toB(): B {
        return new B(this.a, this.c);
    }
}

class B {
    private a: any;
    private c: any;

    constructor(a: any, c: any) {
        this.a = a;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

(and same with class C)

(2) Using interfaces:

```
interface InterfaceBase {
    c: any;
}

interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceBase {
    a: any;
}

interface InterfaceC extends InterfaceBase {
    b: any;
}

interface InterfaceA extends InterfaceB, InterfaceC {
    a: any;
}
```

You can then do the same as in the previous approach ([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20InterfaceBase%20%7B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20InterfaceB%20extends%20InterfaceBase%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20InterfaceC%20extends%20InterfaceBase%20%7B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20InterfaceA%20extends%20InterfaceB%2C%20InterfaceC%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20implements%20InterfaceB%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(a%3A%20any%2C%20c%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.a%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.c%20%3D%20c%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20implements%20InterfaceC%20%7B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(b%3A%20any%2C%20c%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.b%20%3D%20b%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.c%20%3D%20c%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20implements%20InterfaceA%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(a%3A%20any%2C%20b%3A%20any%2C%20c%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.a%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.b%20%3D%20b%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.c%20%3D%20c%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09toB()%3A%20InterfaceB%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20B(this.a%2C%20this.c)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09toC()%3A%20InterfaceC%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20C(this.b%2C%20this.c)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
class B implements InterfaceB {
    a: any;
    c: any;

    constructor(a: any, c: any) {
        this.a = a;
        this.c = c;
    }
}

class A implements InterfaceA {
    a: any;
    b: any;
    c: any;

    constructor(a: any, b: any, c: any) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    toB(): InterfaceB {
        return new B(this.a, this.c);
    }

    toC(): InterfaceC {
        return new C(this.b, this.c);
    }
}
```

Or you can use a single class which can cast itself ([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20InterfaceBase%20%7B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20InterfaceB%20extends%20InterfaceBase%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20InterfaceC%20extends%20InterfaceBase%20%7B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20InterfaceA%20extends%20InterfaceB%2C%20InterfaceC%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20implements%20InterfaceA%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(meta%3A%20InterfaceA)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.a%20%3D%20meta.a%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.b%20%3D%20meta.b%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.c%20%3D%20meta.c%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09asB()%3A%20InterfaceB%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%20as%20InterfaceB%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09asC()%3A%20InterfaceC%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%20as%20InterfaceC%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
class MyClass implements InterfaceA {
    a: any;
    b: any;
    c: any;

    constructor(meta: InterfaceA) {
        this.a = meta.a;
        this.b = meta.b;
        this.c = meta.c;
    }

    asB(): InterfaceB {
        return this as InterfaceB;
    }

    asC(): InterfaceC {
        return this as InterfaceC;
    }
}
```

(3) Another way is to use [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) ([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20HasA%20%7B%0D%0A%09_a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09get%20a()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this._a%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09set%20a(value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._a%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20HasB%20%7B%0D%0A%09_b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09get%20b()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this._b%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09set%20b(value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._b%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20HasC%20%7B%0D%0A%09_c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09get%20c()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this._c%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09set%20c(value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._c%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ClassOne%20implements%20HasA%2C%20HasB%2C%20HasC%20%7B%0D%0A%09_a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09_b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09_c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(a%3A%20any%2C%20b%3A%20any%2C%20c%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.a%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.b%20%3D%20b%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.c%20%3D%20c%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AapplyMixins(ClassOne%2C%20%5BHasA%2C%20HasB%2C%20HasC%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20applyMixins(derivedCtor%3A%20any%2C%20baseCtors%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20derivedCtor.prototype%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20baseCtor.prototype%5Bname%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D)):

```
class HasA {
    _a: any;
    get a(): any {
        return this._a;
    }
    set a(value: any) {
        this._a = value;
    }
}

class HasB {
    _b: any;
    get b(): any {
        return this._b;
    }
    set b(value: any) {
        this._b = value;
    }
}

class HasC {
    _c: any;
    get c(): any {
        return this._c;
    }
    set c(value: any) {
        this._c = value;
    }
}

class ClassOne implements HasA, HasB, HasC {
    _a: any;
    a: any;
    _b: any;
    b: any;
    _c: any;
    c: any;

    constructor(a: any, b: any, c: any) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
applyMixins(ClassOne, [HasA, HasB, HasC]);

function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}
```

(4) You can probably also use the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), but all depends on your scenario.

Comment: I loved the 'Or you can use a single class which can cast itself' approach - very succinct and clear - is there a name for this pattern? many thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think that it's a design pattern, at least not one I'm aware of, more like polymorphism at work

Comment: thank you so much, given me more than i could have dreamed of :) many many thanks -